# Efficient to Update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for an efficient way to Update data in SQL Server, I want to update data `id-B,id-C, and other` if status from `id-A` is `A`, I don't know the UPDATE statement for this conditional.
I need to deal with a lot of records.

This is my example:

```
   -------------------------------
   | Id     | Status|
   -------------------------------
   | 00001-A| A     |
   | 00001-B| I     |
   | 00001-C| I     |
   | 00002-A| A     |
   | 00002-B| I     |
   | 00003-A| I     |
   | 00003-C| I     |
   | 00004-A| I     |
   | 00005-A| A     |
   | 00005-D| I     |
   -------------------------------
```

This The results I want:

```
-------------------------------
   | Id     | Status|
   -------------------------------
   | 00001-A| A     |
   | 00001-B| A     |
   | 00001-C| A     |
   | 00002-A| A     |
   | 00002-B| A     |
   | 00003-A| I     |
   | 00003-C| I     |
   | 00004-A| I     |
   | 00005-A| A     |
   | 00005-D| A     |
```

How can I build the result?
Thank you

Comment: This would be MUCH more straight forward if your `id` colum were split in to two columns, one column for the integer part and one column for the character part.

Comment: I know, but I just continue the projects of other people whose data `ID` are like this, and data rows have reached the millions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an updatable CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(id, 1) = 'A' AND Status = 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY (SUBSTRING(id, 1, CHARINDEX('-', id) - 1))) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET Status = 'A'
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to compute, for each group of `Id` records, a count of when the `Id` ends in `-A` and also the `Status` happens to be `A`.  We then do an update on the status for all `Id` records having this count being greater than zero.